# speed up an If statement with multiple equal to operators for a big DF in R

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, if-statement, time

I'm making a new column which acts as the quarter returns of some other monthly return column. Id like to keep the quarter return data in the representative monthly return data its row. Easy done with the for loop with an if statement included as I show below. However doing so for a DF of 1.000.000 rows is not an option. I wonder how I can do the same trick but then with less computation for R.

```
stock_data$Qret <- NA

for (i in 1:(length(stock_data$YQ_date) - 2)) {
  if (stock_data$YQ_date[i] == stock_data$YQ_date[i + 1] &
      stock_data$YQ_date[i] == stock_data$YQ_date [i + 2]){
    
    stock_data$Qret[i] = (1+ stock_data$ret_excess[i]) * (1+ stock_data$ret_excess[i+1]) * (1 + stock_data$ret_excess[i+2]) -1
    stock_data$Qret[i + 1] = stock_data$Qret[i]
    stock_data$Qret[i + 2] = stock_data$Qret[i] 
      
  } else{ 
    stock_data$Qret[i] = stock_data$Qret[i]
  }
}
```

```
structure(list(ret_excess = c(-0.0387815756200073, 0.0178297872340425, 
-0.326, 0.0691111111111112, -0.138, 0.203111111111111, -0.153595505617977, 
0.0745641025641026, -0.226674418604651, -0.0804782608695652), 
    YQ_date = c(1970.3, 1970.4, 1970.4, 1970.4, 1971.1, 1971.1, 
    1971.1, 1971.2, 1971.2, 1971.2), Qret = c(NA, -0.266571307177305, 
    -0.266571307177305, -0.266571307177305, -0.122209322247191, 
    -0.122209322247191, -0.122209322247191, -0.23588855238713, 
    -0.23588855238713, -0.23588855238713)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using vectorization will make your code a lot faster.  For example:

```
i <- seq_len(nrow(stock_data) - 2)
cond <- stock_data$YQ_date[i] == stock_data$YQ_date[i + 1] &
        stock_data$YQ_date[i] == stock_data$YQ_date [i + 2]
stock_data$Qret[i] <- ifelse(cond, 
                          (1 + stock_data$ret_excess[i]) * 
                          (1 + stock_data$ret_excess[i+1]) * 
                          (1 + stock_data$ret_excess[i+2]) -1, 
                          stock_data$Qret[i])

stock_data$Qret[i + 1][cond] <- stock_data$Qret[i][cond]
stock_data$Qret[i + 2][cond] <- stock_data$Qret[i][cond]
```

This changes the order of operations, so it might give different answers on some data, but it gives the same answer as your code on the sample data.